# Is it possible to get code from a web button on Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I am newbie on Java Spring and I am trying to get the event that is working on a web button. What is the correct way to do this in terms of debug a listener or an event? I mean, I want to find the code that is executed when the user push one button. Is any way to do this using Eclipse or IntelliJ ?

Thanks in advance!

Emma.

Comment: A button can execute many kind of actions, from form submissions to whatever else ( if attached to javascript listeners), what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

A button on a webpage cannot directly call java code as the webpage is displayed on the client and java only runs on the server.
The way client and server generally interact is via requests. For example the client sends a get request and receives a webpage to display.
Generally the way the client sends information back to the server is via [forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) sending post requests to the server which get handled by [spring's @PostMapping methods](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/controller-getmapping-postmapping/) which is where the java code first starts to execute.

If you simply want a button that does something on the client, without interacting with the server then you want to use Javascript with an [onClick event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).